# I keep being rejected by CLI - how to continue using node 8.x.x with Ionic 3 and Cordova 9?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Our project setup is Ionic 3 version, with Cordova 9, and 8.x.x Node.JS.

Everything was relatively fine, until recently, when I started getting this error from command line:

> ERR: Your Node.js version is v8.11.3. Node.js 8 reached end-of-life on
>   2019-12-31 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest
>   Node LTS version.

Usually I am getting it only when I try to build iOS app using Cordova, but sometimes it pops up even when I try to serve locally web app.

It doesn't start any process, the message pops immediately after I try to run a command, and that's it.

I am getting it ONLY on Mac machine, on Windows it works fine. It works fine also from other team members' Mac machines.

Does anyone has any idea how to get rid of it, or go around it? Upgrading Node.js is not an option atm. When I try running Node outside of Ionic project, it works perfectly. It seems that something inside out project refuse to work with 8.x.x Node.

Comment: did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: I found nothing useful googling. And I tried multiple times resesettin and changing node, npm and ionic versions, cleaning dependencies and plugins, reinstalling them...

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is ionic and not node.js. I had new version of ionic installed which didn't support the old node.js version.

first, remove installed ionic version from your system

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

if the command doesn't work remove ionic manually from your .nvm directory or installed global node_module directory also remove ionic CLI executable from /bin directory.

then install ionic 3 using the command.

```
npm install -g ionic@3.2.0
```

Comment: 'npm uninstall -g ionic' this command does nothing. but 'npm install -g ionic@3.2.0' this command does the work for me.